# Erro ao atualizar dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Possuo um repositório base onde realizo apenas CRUD. Ao trabalhar com um dado por vez, o mesmo funciona normalmente. Porém, necessitei realizar uma modificação e enviar vários `records` para ser editado de uma vez. Mas ao realizar isso, eu recebo um erro.

Ao clicar no botão de atualizar, ele procura o dado pelo `Id`, e chega ao método de `Update` com todos os dados para atualização, incluindo o Id. Como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: Método update]

Porém, ao chegar na linha `DbSet.Attach(obj);` eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Attaching an entity of type 'PrestacaoWeb.Domain.Entities.Prestacao' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Olhando [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent) eu observei que o problema é parecido, porém não entendi a resposta, e como aplicar aqui.

Minha Entidade está assim:

```
public class Prestacao
    {
        public Prestacao()
        {
            PrestacaoId = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid PrestacaoId { get; set; }
        public string Uf { get; set; }
        public string Municipio { get; set; }
        public string Orgao { get; set; }
        public string NomeEntidade { get; set; }
        public string TipoPrestacao { get; set; }
        public string Prazo { get; set; }
        public string Responsavel { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public string TipoPendencia { get; set; }
        public string Observacao { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

        public Guid MesId { get; set; }

        public virtual Mes Mes{ get; set; }
    }
```

E meu Controller, está desta forma:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Editar(List<PrestacaoViewModel> prestacaoViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in prestacaoViewModel)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        var prestacao =_prestacaoAppService.ObterPorId(item.PrestacaoId);

                        _prestacaoAppService.Atualizar(prestacao);
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
```

Método de `Update` genérico:

```
public void Update(TEntity obj)
        {
            var entry = Context.Entry(obj);
            DbSet.Attach(obj);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

Comment: Em `var entry = Context.Entry(obj)`, tem algum código embaixo da caixa do inspector?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não possui. Eu adicionei o código completo na pergunta, eu havia esquecido dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto aqui não pode:

```
DbSet.Attach(obj);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Ou você modifica o `State` da `entry`, ou você faz um [`Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). O recomendado é o primeiro, ou seja:

```
public void Update(TEntity obj)
{
    var entry = Context.Entry(obj);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Pela enésima vez vou reiterar: **não use camada service**. Não há a menor necessidade de separar em camada *service* uma aplicação MVC, em que o *Controller* já implementa a função de um *service*.

Isto aqui seleciona o registro duas vezes:

```
if (item != null)
{
    var prestacao =_prestacaoAppService.ObterPorId(item.PrestacaoId);
    _prestacaoAppService.Atualizar(prestacao);
}
```

Faça assim:

```
if (item != null)
{
    _prestacaoAppService.Atualizar(prestacao);
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei sem utilizar o Attach. Porém recebo o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Randrade Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Você retirou a var prestacao, e atualiza ela embaixo?

Comment: `context.Entry(obj)` já localiza um objeto dentro de um contexto (otimisticamente falando). Se você quer a abordagem pessismista, precisa abandonar o padrão *service*: selecionar o registro, modificar propriedade a propriedade, marcar como alterado e chamar o contexto pra salvar.

Answer (score 0):

Se você selecionar o registro e tentar fazer o update vai gerar o erro pois esta entidade vai estar anexada no DbSet evai dar erro de chave duplicada.

```
var prestacao =_prestacaoAppService.ObterPorId(item.PrestacaoId);
_prestacaoAppService.Atualizar(prestacao);
```

para que não ocorra este erro você terá que enviar apenas o item da viewmodel sem obter novamente a entidade

```
foreach (var item in prestacaoViewModel)
{
     if (item != null)
     {
         _prestacaoAppService.Atualizar(item);
     }
}
```

Caso seja necessário verificar se o registro está cadastrado você pode sobrescrever seu método genérico no seu repositório para poder desanexar a entidade do DbSet.

```
public override Prestacao Update(Prestacao prestacao)
{
      // primeiro encontra a entidade para atualizar
      var oldEntity = DbSet.Find(prestacao.PrestacaoId);
     // desanexar esta entidade do DbSet
      Db.Entry(oldEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;

      var entry = Db.Entry(prestacao);
      DbSet.Attach(prestacao);
      entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
      return prestacao;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo using do contexto esse contexto é criado somente dentro das chaves.
Este erro ocorre porque existe um conflito de chaves primárias, instaciando um contexto dentro do metodo você abrira e fechara a conexão com o banco dentro do mesmo método evitando esse conflito.

using (var contexto = new Contexto()) {

```
            contexto.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
            contexto.SaveChanges();
 }
```